# C# Json.NET - Deserialize Dictionary<object, float>

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I've dictionary with objects as key and a float as value. The value is the chance to instance an object instead an other.
I've to save it in a JSON (using JSON.NET - Newtonsoft) to read it later, but I can't find a solution.
**N.B.: It's not a game or a Unity project**
I've tried these format:

```
"Droppables" : [{
  {  
      "DroppableType": "LnUP",
      "SpriteFileName": "Projectile 1.png"
  },
  0.15
},
{
  {
      "DroppableType": "AnUP",
      "SpriteFileName": "Projectile 2.png"
  },
  0.15
}]
```

```
"Droppables" : [
{
    "DroppableType": "LnUP",
    "SpriteFileName": "Projectile 1.png"
},
0.15
},
{
    "DroppableType": "AnUP",
    "SpriteFileName": "Projectile 2.png"
},
0.15
]
```

```
"Droppables" : {
{
    "DroppableType": "LnUP",
    "SpriteFileName": "Projectile 1.png"
},
0.15
},
{
{
    "DroppableType": "AnUP",
    "SpriteFileName": "Projectile 2.png"
},
0.15
}
```

and many others, but nothing works.
Is there a manner or I've to use an other struct?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) ?

Comment: @PhilippeB.Yes, I'm using it. I've written in the tile, now I add also in question, sorry :)

Comment: @ProtoTyPus Did you try observing the result when you serialize your existing dictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary having an object as a key has no representation in Json format. You need to use a proxy type to convert your dictionary to a more suitable structure like below :

```
public class Proxy
{
    public string DroppableType { get; set; }
    public string SpriteFileName { get; set; }
    public float Probability { get; set; }
}

// before you serialize 

var result = yourDictionary.Select(t=> new Proxy { 
                Probability = t.Value, 
                DroppableType = t.DroppableType,
                SpriteFileName = t.SpriteFileName 
            }).ToArray();

// for deserializing it

var dictionary = deserialized.ToDictionary(r=> new YourType { r.DroppableType, r.SpriteFileName  },r=>Probability);
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure? :(

Comment: @ProtoTyPus 1) Why you need to use an object as a key. 2) What's wrong with using a proxy class? Also, note that you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`  methods of your object in order to make it work consistent with dictionary.

Comment: Keys in JSON must be string (see here https://www.json.org/json-en.html). With this limitation it seems your choice is to either massage your dictionary or to extend the serialiser (Newtonsoft library has a few points you can plug into) so it knows what sort of output to generate